# How to escape "<" to be spoken by Microsoft Speech Api v5.4?

Tags: java, sapi

I can't play a message that contains `<`. From what I understood it is because it's considered as a XML tag. I could not find a way to escape it.

I tried to replace it by `&lt;` and play that chars literally. Also tried `SPEAKFLAGS SPF_IS_NOT_XML`, then it speaks the text but ignores the `<`.

Is there any way to easily speak "lower than" when it finds `<`, as it does with `>`?

Comment: did you try `&lt;` or just `&lt` ?